# Are questions about how to detect something out of an image using an 3rd party API too broad?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-answers

I am wondering about this question:

[How to detect whether a head is completely or only party inside an image frame with Google Vision API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50782221/1870795)

The question is about

- how the API can be used to detect whether a head is cropped off
- a purpose that is not mentioned in the [API docs](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-faces)

The question received close votes with comments that

- "we are not a code writing service", although the question is not asking for code
- "you wanted us to read the documentation for you to explain what code to write" although the question is not asking for code writing and the purpose is not mentioned in the API docs.

It also puzzles me that even a valid answer to the question has been 
voted down and received a delete vote. If a question is really too broad the answer can still be valid and helpful to others. The answer solves the problem, containing *undocumented* insight into the API by demonstrating with an example image:

- the API results for different types of face bounds
- the relation between the face bounds and the head part of the image

Should an API related question be asked on SO or is it better placed in another SE community?

Comment: Unfortunately some people see every question that isn't an overly useless debugging question as too broad. Yes your question is on-topic, no it isn't too broad.

Comment: It is on topic, but I maintain that the question and answer are too broad. You might want to consider adding in a bit more of your research, or showing how your problem can be solved (with some code, because I still maintain that the only thing that can convince me your question isn't too broad is if you demonstrate that it indeed is a simple problem to solve).

Comment: I didn't vote in this case, but I'd argue that it lacks evidence of research. Meta opinion is divided on this: some people say that a clear question with no research is on-topic because it is useful for future readers notwithstanding. I personally think the Stack Overflow model cannot scale (and is not scaling _present tense_) for questions without research. (FWIW I tend not to vote as Too Broad if there is an accompanying answer, since the pair of posts are useful taken together, even if the question on its own might be closeworthy).

Comment: (Upvote here though for the constructive way it has been brought to _Meta_).

Comment: I'm voting to close your question as off topic since it does not appear you are interested in seeking input from the community, based on your out lashes against other users in the comment sections. The only thing you've succeeded with bringing this issue to meta is direct the meta effect towards your posts. You are only interested in listening to voices that are supporting your agenda, whatever that might be.

Comment: @coldspeed Alright, thanks for the interesting discussion. It helped me to better understand this community.

Comment: This question clearly seeks input and discussion, I find the close vote surreal.

Comment: @peterh: it is going a bit off the rails in the comments under coldspeed's answer. I think the original question above is excellent (and I upvoted it), but if disagreeing with the premise of the question makes folks "rampantly elitist and political", that casts some doubt on whether the OP is willing to tolerate disagreement. I have not VTC, for what it's worth - it is probably better to have a frayed discussion than none at all.

Comment: @halfer By closing the question with an obviously false reason, you are essentially proving his statement. In a free voting environment is it irrelevant, how the OP tolerates disagreement, he can't avoid the downs, he can't avoid a disagreeing answer (but a closure would avoid), and voting something to close because disagreement is going directly against the SE concepts, if it is not even a power misuse.

Comment: @Manuel There is no other SE site I know, where this question could be asked (another candidate, Android SE, forbids programming questions, probably on a yet more surrealistic reason why your this question, and the original question, got the close votes).

Comment: @peterh you seem to be white knighting without having read the entire discussion. Comments like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369270/are-questions-about-api-usage-too-broad/369273?noredirect=1#comment598913_369273) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369270/are-questions-about-api-usage-too-broad/369273?noredirect=1#comment598891_369273) indicate OP's tendency to respond to criticism by saying it is a "waste of time", or "I am walking out", or "you are rampant elitists". Sorry, but please read the situation.

Comment: @peterh: I see your point. However, a close reason of "does not seek input and discussion" (to use the official wording) would not be "false" - it would merely be another point of disagreement. If the close voters are of that opinion, then I can see their point too - which illustrates why I think the OP's language is unfortunate. I agree that the OP may feel vindicated if this closes, but it would be a hollow victory. I would like him to use more moderate language to indicate that in fact he _is_ interested in input and discussion. I would also like the Q to stay open `:-)`.

Comment: [1/2] @Manuel: I was the person to introduce the word "strategy" and I apologise if it offended you. I think it is an extremely neutral word from debating contents, and essentially it means "how you are going to argue your case". It is exactly the same context as the phase "legal strategy" i.e. how a lawyer will argue for her client in court. I agree this is meta-meta, but words matter, and I am happy to clear up any misunderstandings.

Comment: [2/2] My usage of the word was to outline the view that approaching a community for a discussion, while using intemperate language against the community, might not aid your cause. That in itself is not a radical view, I think.

Comment: That I was not interested in input sounds just like another accusation. Having the opinion that SO has become overly political is valid, just maybe better suited in a question on its own. Also I added constraints to my original question as suggested in the comments here.

Comment: @Manuel: sure, I understand that you feel that you've been accused of not wanting a discussion, and hopefully you can see why people have suggested that. But don't let other people's language derail your question - your end goal, is to see what changes (if any) are necessary to your Q&A to get them considered on-topic, right?

Comment: @halfer Exactly, or to stand corrected and not post these kind of question on SO anymore. Any rule of this community would be sufficiently acceptable for me, but not subjective assumptions.

Comment: @coldspeed disagreement in the comments does not make a question off topic. That's an abuse of close voting.

Comment: @halfer I am surprised that it does not outrage you that my past questions are getting down-voted as a form of revenge. I find it pretty outraging, culturally, not because I'm loosing rep, frankly I couldn't care less about these rep points.

Comment: @Manuel: I can't respond to every minor item that you mention, but given that you've said you are keen for folks not to make assumptions, perhaps you shouldn't either? Whether or not I should be outraged at this or that thing sounds like another derailment, and I advocate against it. (For the record, I am opposed to revenge downvoting. Can we stick to the question?)

Comment: @YvetteColomb with all due respect, it wasn't the nature of the disagreement, it was the language being used.

Comment: @coldspeed that still has nothing to do with whether or not a question is on topic. If people are using inappropriate language, flag it.

Comment: @YvetteColomb No, it wasn't a question of inappropriate language. The OP's responses to Olaf and myself indicated that they were not interested in listening to our points of view. If you see their first comment under my post (now moved to chat), you'll see the discourse was a lot more open-minded, until Tiny Giant made their comments.

Comment: @coldspeed I am aware of those comments. They're still irrelevant, as the question is on topic. If the OP wants to argue about your POV, you don't need to engage them. My point is, what is said in the comments is not relevant to the actual question. The question is self contained and on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's **take a step back** from the minutiae of close reasons and evidence of research. It's important to have guidelines, but in the end SO is about providing useful Q&A. Guidelines work one way: all clear & not broad & mcve-containing, etc, questions are not for closing. But that doesn't mean a useful Q&A *must* have all these features. That would be a logical fallacy.

I'm pretty sure almost everyone discussing this Meta has never used the API in question, or read the documentation in detail. In such a case, we generally can't tell a priori whether the Q&A will be useful to other users of the API.

But **we can make judgement calls** to close / reopen and, especially for low-volume tags, reviewing posts in unfamiliar tags is an unfortunate necessity. *Theoretically*, you'd want to survey the target audience, other users of [google-cloud-vision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-vision). Sadly, the tag is [not at all](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-cloud-vision/topusers) popular, so this isn't an option.

Given all the above, all I can ask myself is, "If someone using API X wants to detect whether a head is wholly included in a picture, **would they find this question helpful?**" In both the original and new state, I can't deny it *would* be useful...

The question isn't just asking how to detect heads but it's asking for a **special case** not explicitly dealt with in the documentation, i.e. how to detect a head has been cropped-off. If I was a user of this API and didn't know which method to use, I wouldn't know where to start. Sharing some code showing how to access the API isn't likely to add value either.

Comment: This seem to be the most conciliatory, sober-minded and non-technocratic answer in this whole thread. I think it is setting a perfect example of the culture we should live by on SO.

Comment: @halfer, While what you say *may* be true, your comment is just an opinion. While it's true not many people *agree* with my post, it's also true that it's not downvoted to oblivion. An equally valid description for +4 / -2 could be "the community is ambivalent with respect to this answer".

Comment: Thanks @jpp. My remark was not really based on your votes, but the very mixed scores on the original post (17/-16) and the high scores on Makyen and coldspeed's posts. I was worried that the casual reader might see the tick/check mark and mistake it for a settled community consensus, when in fact it just indicates the OP agrees with himself `;-)`.

Comment: @halfer, Yep, that's a very good point, indeed. I took particular care *not* to upvote Manuel's comment to my answer. While this answer reflects my viewpoint, the green tick in itself means little.

Comment: No significant percentage of community members have voted, so it can by no means be inferred that the answer is *or is not* representative of the community’s opinion. The green tick means what is always means on SE and what is described in the guidelines: the post best answers the OP‘s question according to the OP. Otherwise there would be no such feature and the correct answer was determined automatically by voting results. I am surprised that has to be explicitly clarified.

Answer (score 21):

Questions about API usage are on-topic. However, your specific question was/is not on-topic, because of the specifics of the question, not a general moratorium on asking questions about APIs.

Personally, I voted to close as unclear/too broad because you didn't define what you meant by some of the things you stated in the Question, nor what results you actually wanted for each input. Importantly, your self-answer didn't fully answer the Question, as I understood it. The fact that you added that Answer indicated there was a disconnect between what you wrote in the Question and what you were actually looking for when asking your question. I don't remember which of "too broad" or "unclear" that I actually voted, but I felt that both could fit. [Note: [this is the version which was closed](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50782221/1).]

Self-answered questions must be sufficiently clear and contain enough information such that others who are familiar with the technology used can A) see that the self-answer does, in fact, completely answer the question, and B) could come up with an Answer which answers the question (i.e. satisfies the OP). The self-answer defines what the OP believes to be acceptable as an answer. IMO, the Answer you posted did not fully answer the Question as it was written (or as it's written as I post this). That confirms the question is unclear/too broad and must be narrowed/clarified, such that the self-answer is a complete answer to the question.

### The issues with the question

#### Clarity

You provided 3 input images and asked for all three how to use the API "to detect if a head is completely inside an image or cut off by the image frame". This implies that you want to know A) if there is a head in the image and B) if that head is entirely in the frame. To me this means that you are looking for the results:

```
image    head?   is entirely in frame
  1      true           true
  2      true           false
  3      true           false
```

If that is not what you expected to get, then you needed to define what you mean by a head being in the image and/or what a cut-off head is.

#### Too broad

It's not clear to me that the API can accomplish the detection that there is a head and that it's cut-off for image 3. The probable complexity of doing that puts this out of the range of an SO answer.

The question doesn't define if it's only looking for an answer to these specific images, or something that's more generalized. Perhaps it could narrow this down by just saying that it's asking only about images which the API actually detects as having a head. However, it doesn't do that, and specifically includes an example which has a head that's cut-off which is supposed to be detected as a cut-off head, but for which the API doesn't even detect the existence of the head.

The question, [at the time of closure](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50782221/1), is basically asking someone to code up the entirety of this project to provide the above results. While that might be possible in a SO answer, it makes a *much* better question to break the problem into the various sub-tasks that are needed to solve the problem and ask separately about each of those sub-tasks, because those are at the level which can be reusable pieces that others can benefit from.

### Answer confirms question is unclear/too broad

Your answer shows only results from the API for image 1 and image 2 with image 3 greyed out. Thus, the results you were showing indicated that, for image 3, the API did not detect A) that there was a head in the frame, which was required by the question, as written.

For image 3 you state a conclusion that is unjustified by the results that you are showing. You state "the API does not result any `faceAnnotations`, so it can be easily detected as a substantially cropped-off head." From what you've shown, based on the results from the API, there is no justification to believe that there is a head *at all* in the image. It could be a picture of a garbage truck and get the same non-results. Thus, "easily detected as a substantially cropped-off head" is clearly a false conclusion/assumption.

If this was not a self-answer:

1. I would have just assumed that it was a poor/incomplete answer.
2. I would have commented on the answer asking the author to address the above issues, and potentially others.

#### Self-answers reflect on the quality/completeness of the Question

Because it was a self-answer, it reflects even more on the Question than an answer from some other person. By posting the self-answer, an OP has basically defined what they feel is an answer to the question which they actually intended to ask. Because this self-answer does not answer the Question as I understand the Question, it's clear that the Question which was written was not the question which the OP is actually asking. This confirms that the question is either unclear or too broad.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to elaborate. Without going into the details because this has taken too many people’s time already, I just wanna say this: If it gets to a point where asking a question on SO becomes so complicated as apparent by this discussion then SO defies it’s own (original) purpose. As with every community it is normal to see forms of elitism and bureaucracy evolving, but if it is not contained it won’t do any good to the future of this community.

Comment: @Manuel: I'm with Makyen here. The answer does only answers the question when it is already clear that the pictures will definitely show a face (and only one face) and that the asker already knows how to detect faces with this API. When only reading the question, I'd expect an answer to show how to detect the face first.

Comment: @BDL It is an essential feature of the API to detect faces. Why would the asker need to explain the API? The answer is tagged appropriately and should be routed to user who are knowledgeable of the API. What am I missing here?

Comment: @Manuel: Then there is a general problem with the methodology used in the question. One could easily construct a image where the top part of the face is covered by something else in the image. In this case the 4 top-points would be missing although the face would not be intersected by the image frame. Other problem: When the head is tilted, at least one of the bounding polygon points could be outside of the image although the face is completely visible. Just testing the bounding box is just an indication, not a full answer.

Comment: @BDL These are all valid points and *already part of the conclusion*, I’d be happy to read them in an answer under *caveats*. People come to SO to develop a solution. A supremely efficient and effective solution rarely exists, then there would be little need to ask a question.

Comment: [1/2] @Manuel: That's exactly my point. You stated a question which cannot be solved in a way that is suitable for the SO format "How do I detect if a face on an image is cropped off". (-> too broad). Then you drop in and answer the way more constraint subproblem "How do I detect if a face on an image is cropped of under the assumption that a) I already know that the image will always contain a head b) I have already detected the face with the API and know where in the image it is, c) There is nothing else on the image that covers the face, d) It only has to work when the head is not tilted.

Comment: [2/2] @Manuel: If an answer like that wouldn't have been from the question author, I definitely would have downvoted it and left a comment like "This answer only covers a small part of the answer and will not work in a lot of cases".
For me this answer is very similar to answering "How can I print data from a SQL database" by stating "Get the data to an array, then loop over it and use the print command". Yes, it answers part of the question, but is not really helpful to anybody.

Comment: I see many people disappointed that there are no code lines to immerse into ;-) Joke aside, we simply disagree on what’s *suitable for the SO format*. That is fair and we’ll see if the Q&A helps anyone.

Comment: @Manuel At least from my POV, we disagree as to the question being *clear* as to what you're asking and *too broad* due to lacking constraints assumed for your answer. Questions, and answers, don't *inherently* need code. It would be relatively easy for you to edit the question to clarify it and narrow it, so that it actually reflects the question that your answer implies you intended to ask.

Comment: @Makyen I gladly clarify it. Your assumption a) does not apply as if there is no face in the image the API will detect that out of the box, b) to detect the face position is a main API feature so no need to clarify that, c) if a face is fully covered then there won’t be a face in the image *by definition* and how much a partly covered face is detected by the API is an API quality constraint so no need to speculate about unpublished API quality, d) it works also when the head is titled as the face tilt is recognized by the API out of the box. What exactly do you want to clarify?

Comment: @Manuel Well, to me, the main thing would be to make it clear that you're interested in determining that the head is cut-off *only for images in which the API detects a (single?) head/face*. Doing so significantly narrows the question from all images to just those from which the API is giving you face/head info, which is what your answer implies you intended to ask. I'd also make clear what your images are examples of: 1. Head which isn't cut-off; 2. Cut-off head; 3. API does not detect a head/face, so ignore image. This latter portion helps clarify exactly what you are expecting as a result.

Comment: @Makyen I think I understand what you mean. Are you saying that the answer does not differentiate between the image of a body with a completely cut off heat which should be interpreted as `cutOffHead=true` and the image of a tree which should be interpreted as `cutOffHead=false` because there is not even a person in the image?

Comment: @Manuel I'm saying you haven't made it clear that you are interested in being able to say `cutOffHead=true` or `cutOffHead=false` *only* when the API detects a head in the image. If the API doesn't detect a head, then `hasHead=false` & you don't care about `cutOffHead`, regardless of what a human might say as to there being a head in the image, or not.

Comment: This is implied by your answer, but your question doesn't limit what you're attempting to determine to just that subset, *and* you give an example in the question of an image that does have a head that's cut-off, but where the API doesn't recognize that there's a head, which, by being in the question, implies you want it correctly detected as `hasHead=true` and `cutOffHead=true`.

Comment: @Makyen Good point, I’ll add that to the question.

Comment: @Makyen added, if you can please review would be great :)

Comment: FWIW: _"Because this self-answer does not answer the Question as I understand the Question"_ it answers the question as I understand the question _perfectly_, so maybe the problem is your understanding of the question, and not the question itself.

Comment: @TinyGiant No, it's not. The fact that different people end up with different understandings of the question is the *definition* of being unclear. Sure, if it was *only* me, then perhaps I just misread it (it happens). However, it's clear from the discussion here that many people interpret the question similarly to how I do, or at least significantly differently than is implied by the Answer the OP wrote for their question. Under other circumstances, I'd be happy to admit that, perhaps, it was only me who misread the question, but that's not the case here.

Comment: I don't know. The only way I can see the question being seen as unclear or too broad is with a lack of understanding of the subject matter at hand.

Comment: @TinyGiant For me, the only way I can see the question being clear :-) is if I take the assumptions about the question which are inherent in the Answer and fold them back into the Question. My intent yesterday was to edit the Question to incorporate those assumptions, but that's not possible right at the moment, due to the Question being locked. It's not that I don't think the question can't be clear and not to broad, just that it's not there yet, and definitely wasn't there (IMO) at the time the Question was closed.

Comment: @Makyen I would be interested to see your edits on my question. Just before you do be aware that I’m not “interested in determining that the head is cut-off only for images in which the API detects a head/face” but in which there is a head partly visible for the human eye. How much face the API needs to detect a face is an API limitation and and part of an answer. And if only a neck is visible then it would be as wrong to assume that there was a head outside the image bounds as that there wasn’t a head. Answer is unlocked, please feel free.

Answer (score 9):

> Should an API related question be asked on SO or is it better placed
>   in another SE community?

Questions about API usage are on-topic.

**However.**

If you inspect the question, you'll see it wasn't closed because of the nature of the topic being asked, it was because of the fact that the question was **Too Broad.** The question was asked in such a way that coming up with any answer that even comes close to answering the question in its entirety would be require way more effort than it's worth.

Judging by the fact that the question was answered by yourself (the OP), this *may* have been construed as an effort to earn some quick rep, which likely factored into the closure of your question. The community usually tends to hold self-posts to a higher standard than normal Q&As after all.

If you want to genuinely contribute with a good, solid Q&A, it isn't impossible. Many have done so in the past. Just make sure your question ticks all the boxes, is well researched, and answerable within the guidelines set down by the help centre and the community.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172857/discussion-on-answer-by-coldspeed-are-questions-about-api-usage-too-broad).

Comment: @TinyGiant - At the time Yvette responded to the "too many comments" flag, there were already 44 comments here. The comments appear to me to be devolving into an argument, which might be best hashed out in chat. Comment threads extending in this way are often moved to chat, even on Meta. This answer was the only one to generate a "too many comments" flag, so this is the one she acted on.

Comment: @TinyGiant I don't usually move-to-chat comments on meta, but this is one that even I would probably have done so due to the number of comments. Let's not make assumptions about motives. Instead just follow the conversation to the location it was moved to. It's not hidden, everyone can read it.

Comment: @Tiny Giant: Your reasons for not using chat are your own, but twisting that to make it sound like the mods are deleting comments without *any* recourse for continuing the conversation (even if we're technically deleting them here as far as the Q&A system is concerned) is just despicable. (I'm not saying this to try and sway you because you've probably long made your mind up about us, I'm just informing readers what exactly it is you're doing here.)

Comment: @boltclock no I see how it is. My opinion isn't worth anything so it can be easily relegated to a back room out of the way where my opinion couldn't possibly upset your sandbox. Just informing future readers what exactly it is you're doing here.

Comment: @TinyGiant Um, what are you on? It's not like your comments were the only ones that were moved - so were mine and the others' as well. I was getting sick of the notifications _anyway_.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I don't have much of an axe to grind in this case - I have given an answer on the "other side" to you, but I don't feel very strongly about it. However, I wanted to add a small amount of meta-commentary. You're a valued member of this community and you've made a lot of great contributions in the past, but I don't recall you pushing this hard or apparently getting this frustrated before. I mean this as a kindness, but is it worth taking a break from SO? This discussion isn't really all that important, in the scheme of things.

Comment: @halfer please don't pretend to know what is important to me. I think it would be worth it for all of the people who are frustrated by seeing reasonable on-topic questions to take a break. I think if reasonable on-topic questions frustrate users to the point that every question they lay their eyes on appears to be off-topic in someway or another, that would be a good time to take a break. Sadly these users generally just stick around and continue making a mess of everything for everyone else.

Comment: I'm not pretending anything, @TinyGiant, and I assure you that my remark is well-motivated. I am not taking issue with your opinion on this topic: I am just observing that if a valued member of the community is directing hostility at several mods, it is a cause for concern. We're allowed to be concerned for each other here, right? `:-)`

Comment: @TinyGiant With all due respect, there's a glaring issue with bad questions, people who're willing to answer them, people who're willing to give them a pass, and people who just don't care. If you aren't helping solve the problem, then perhaps you are part of the problem. This is going to be my last comment here, but hopefully there shall come a time when we can actually agree on something together. Cheers.

Comment: @coldspeed the problem is that the question is not bad. Not even remotely. My close votes age away on truly off-topic content while reasonable on-topic content is stomped on with prejudice. So maybe a big part of the problem, as far as I can see, is people so concerned with closing every question ever asked that they miss the forest for the trees and just make a mess of everything for everyone else. At least as far as I can see.

Answer (score 3):

It strikes me that there is a lot of discussion already on the exact reasons that this question is considered, by some people, to be Unclear or Too Broad. However, your aim is to get this question answered, so my general advice would be: make some modifications to the question to satisfy the objections. You do not have to fully agree with the need to add that material; I would suggest just doing it in order to get the assistance you require.

Since this is an API, what I would recommend is to write a short piece of code (e.g. a Curl command from a terminal) to call the remote server and show how the results are not satisfactory. This can then be added into your question as evidence of research, and as a base from which interested readers can modify your call to achieve what you are setting out to do. If you could can edit your question now to do that, I would certainly cast a reopen vote, and I would be likely to upvote for your willingness to act on requests for improvement.

The answer mentions `boundingPoly` and `fdBoundingPoly`, and that these things are provided for the API in question, but since the question is "How to detect a cropped-off head with Google Vision API", the answer feels rather partial. Having read your answer, I still would not be able to answer this question at all. Thus, if you can edit your self-answer with a modified Curl call to show *how* to do the thing you were initially confused about, that would be an excellent way to help future readers. That would be likely to attract upvotes over time as well.

For what it is worth, I do not think the adding of a small amount of code, to either or both of the question and the answer, will harm either.

Comment: Adding code to the question and answer just for the sake of making it look like a debugging issue does still not make sense to me, unless there is a rule on SO that code must be included. We have been there already in the discussion. I will gladly clarify my question - but not with a CURL command on how call an API as that is 101, has nothing to do with my question and the API docs provide plenty of CURL examples.

Comment: So your suggestion is to turn this reasonably scoped on-topic non-debugging question into a useless debugging question. The question is asking if there is information exposed by the API that can be used to determine If the image satisfies the given criteria. Should they explain every piece of information provided by the API which does not help determine this? That seems like a huge waste of time for irrelevant nonsense.

Comment: @Manuel: the suggestion of adding code does not have to be motivated by a desire to turn the question into a debugging issue, and indeed that was not my justification. My reason for it was to allow you to demonstrate prior research, as well as giving some commands that readers could extend or modify to achieve your goals.

Comment: Prior research is not required for the question to be on-topic. There is no lack of research effort close reason. I mean duplicate yes, but no one has proposed a duplicate yet.

Comment: Put another way: would it be so _terrible_ to add the line(s) of code I suggest, in order to reopen the question, @Manuel? There is always going to be some disagreement at the edges of closure, as this discussion shows - this addition can be part of the give and take, perhaps?

Comment: Making this about code is just muddying the waters because any code outside of the names of properties is completely irrelevant to the question asked.

Comment: I think your position and my position may be too far away, @TinyGiant, in order for us to come to an agreement. That, of course, is OK - sometimes disagreement is just the state of things. I don't feel very strongly about this case, and if I had seen the Q&A pair I would likely not have closed them. However, I am of the view they were closed in good faith. I think the approaches I have outlined in my answer would be a good way out of the impasse, and doing them would not harm the question, and it would significantly improve the answer.

Comment: But everything that you propose is irrelevant noise in the context of the question. I mean yeah you're checking the boxes on the script but none of it matters for the question. None of it. It's acceptable the way it is and none of that stuff would make it better. All of that stuff would add noise and decrease signal guaranteeing that it would be a worse question. I fail to see how that can possibly be beneficial.

Comment: @TinyGiant: that seems like a restatement of your view, and we are still in disagreement, for the reasons I have already outlined.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I can see what halfer means. When there is no "current status" code in the question, an answer has to assume that there is no prior working code. In this case the answer has to start from scratch, which means in this case by explaining how to identify faces by using the API. Since the answer assumes that this is already done, the question should reflect that. So see it as you want, either the questions needs to show the current status (by showing code or in text form) or the answer has to answer the full question.

Comment: @BDL I agree. It should have been made clearer in the first version of the question that the question is not code-related nor does it expect code in the answer. This has later been added to the question.

Comment: @BDL the "current status" code is [provided in the docs referenced by the OP](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-faces) (see: "Detecting Faces in a remote image") in 8 languages which is all of two or three lines of code in most of the languages documented there; but is completely irrelevant because this is not a question about code, nor is it a question about detecting faces. It's a question about the information contained in a face detection API response.

Answer (score -7):

I think you are right that it wasn't a particularly useful review.

However, you are a 3k+ user, thus you *can* cast close and reopen votes, both here and on the main site.

This site depends on the *community self-organising*.

You are essentially requesting us to vote better.

However, the VtC review queue stays around 8000 now, and the majority of the VtC reviews are simply expiring.

What you've faced, despite the many pro and contra arguments what you've read, is essentially an over-reaction of the VtC voters trying to clean up the site.

Now, in the comment chat, I helped you as I only could - but note: although they are voting

- sometimes badly
- sometimes unfairly
- sometimes they are elitist killing informative, useful questions
- sometimes they are anti-elitist welcoming crap

**...but the reason, why you shouldn't face that terrible crap flooding everything on the Internet, is their work.**

You [didn't ever vote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1870795/manuel?tab=activity) in any review queue on the Meta site, and you did only [3 reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870795/manuel?tab=activity) on the main site, roughly 1 per year, since you are a 3k+ user.

You want a better review mechanism?

## **[Then come and help us!](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/)**

Comment: I think asking people to volunteer is good advice generally, but I am not sure if it is entirely related to the question at hand. The question here is whether the linked question, as presented, is on-topic.

Comment: @halfer The answer is specific to this question, that the reason of the VtC was obviously that the reviewers had no time. I am starting to thinking, that even already that "bad world" started around 2014, what I mentioned in the comments, were started on this reason.

Comment: @halfer Well, although I honor the crap cleanup work of the 3k+ MSO users, their communication style I really can't... and also not their voting customs. You have *really* a problem that I said "Review" and not "Review Queue"???

Comment: Sorry, just looking for clarity, Peter - have I offended you? I am detecting hostility, which I was not expecting. I had wondered if the CVs came from SO-CVR, so it was an honest question. (Understanding how the voting came about may or may not be relevant, but it does not seem to be a contentious sub-topic, unless I am missing something?)

Comment: @halfer No... to make clear: "review" is an issue about a post. A HTML representation of a review is, for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/16946376). A "review queue" is a list of ongoing reviews, there are 8 of them, and the most important in them is the [Close Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close) queue. I can't see anything where I wrote that badly...

Comment: @halfer Okay. The first close vote puts the question also in the VtC queue, and it remains here until the review 1) expires 2) gets 3 "leave open" votes 3) gets 5 VtC votes (golden tag badge owners in dupe matters, and mods in all cases have decisive vote in both directions). As far I know, the majority of the close votes happen from a review queue, although close/reopen votes can be cast also from the queues independently.